# Registry key for global proxy settings for Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, proxy, registry, internet-explorer-10

I have a program that sets proxy settings and it has worked through prior versions of Windows until Windows 8 and IE 10.  It sets the keys below.  In Windows 8, other browsers (like firefox) recognize the change and use the proxy settings.  For IE 10, the global policy goes into effect (settings greyed out) but not the proxy settings themselves.  If I set ProxySettingsPerUser to 1 and copy the same keys inth HKCU, then IE uses them for the current user ... but I need this to cover all users.

```
HKLM "SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel" "Proxy" = 1  
HKLM "SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Control Panel" "AutoConfig" = 1  
HKLM "SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" "ProxySettingsPerUser" = 0  
HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" "DialupUseLanSettings" = 1  
HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" "WarnOnIntranet" = 0  
HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" "ProxyEnable" = 1  
HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" "MigrateProxy" = 1  
HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" "ProxyServer" = <server name>  
HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" "ProxyOverride" = <list of exceptions>
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question; are you searching for the value in Internet Explorer 10 or are you looking for a way to recursively modify all your client users at one time?

Comment: I am wanting to set the proxy for all present and future users.

Answer (score 5):

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"ProxySettingsPerUser"=dword:00000000

Answer (score 0):

Create a .reg file containing your proxy settings for your users.
Create a batch file setting it to setting it to run the .reg file with the extension /s

On a server using a logon script, tell the logon to run the batch file.
Jason

Answer (score 0):

TRY

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings

EnableAutoProxyResultCache = dword: 0